# No suitable conversion function from std::vector<Object *, std::allocator<Object *>>" to "Object *" exists

Tags: c++, pointers

Not sure where I'm going wrong.. I have two classes like so:

```
class One
{
    public:
    vector<Object*> myObjects;
};

class Two
{
    public:
    vector<Object*> * pointertoObjects;
};
```

I then want to create a pointer from pointertoObjects to myObjects and am doing so like this:

```
pointertoObjects = &myObjects;
```

But when I try to access to pass through an element:

```
void doFunction(Object * object);
doFunction(pointertoObjects[i])
```

it gives me an error:

```
Error: no suitable conversion function from std::vector<Object *, std::allocator<Object *>>" to "Object *" exists
```

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: The compiler is telling you exactly where the problem is.

Comment: I know that but I dont know how to fix! :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
pointertoObjects[i]
```

This treats the pointer as the address of the start of an array of `vector` objects, and gives you element `i` of that array. (Since there isn't an array, just a single vector, you'll get undefined behaviour if `i` is non-zero).

If you want element `i` of the vector that the pointer points to, then that's:

```
(*pointertoObjects)[i]
```

or with range-checking and less scope for accidental type errors:

```
pointertoObjects->at(i)
```

You should ask yourself whether you really need so many pointers; they can get quite confusing.

Comment: Thanks a lot :D Worked greated

Answer (score 1):

When you write `pointertoObjects[i]`, you are dereferencing `pointertoObjects` and C++ behaves like it was an array of `vector<Object*>`, so `pointertoObjects[i]` yields a (reference to) `vector<Object*>`.

To fix that:

```
(*pointertoObjects)[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a simple type mismatch.  When you use array indexing on `pointertoObjects`, you get a reference to a `vector<Object*>`, not the `Object *` required by `doFunction`.

You probably want something like this:  `doFunction((*pointertoObjects)[i]);`

Comment: Ah, so how can I access the object in the specified array index?

Answer (score 0):

```
vector<Object*> pointedObjects = *pointertoObjects;
Object* obj = pointedObjects[i]
doFunction(obj);
```